# Problem with creating a resource & strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is using Rails for the API and React for the client. My attempts to create a resource are failing. I want to get one value (description) from the user and provide defaults for the rest.

Here's the server log:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/goals" for ::1 at 2020-09-21 07:05:13 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::GoalsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"goal"=>{"description"=>"Leggo"}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "fake@email.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 14791)



RuntimeError (<ActionController::Parameters {"goal"=>{"description"=>"Leggo"}, "controller"=>"api/v1/goals", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>):

app/controllers/api/v1/goals_controller.rb:52:in `goal_params'
app/controllers/api/v1/goals_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

The controller action:

```rb
  def create
    @goal = Goal.new(goal_params, user_id: current_user.id, complete: false, category_id: 1)

    if @goal.save
      render json: @goal, status: :created, location: @goal
    else
      render json: @goal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The strong params method:

```rb
    def goal_params
      raise params.inspect
      params.fetch(:goal).permit(:description)
    end
```

And the client-side request:

```js
    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url,
        headers,
        data: { goal: { description } }
      });
      console.log('Created goal');
      setDescription('');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: use `params.require(:goal).permit(......)`.

Comment: Gives me the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Are you getting the error because you're raising the error? Is this line 52: `raise params.inspect`?

Comment: Yeah but without that line I get `422 Unprocessable Entity`. So I think there is a problem with the params?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `raise params.inspect` firstly.

If you're getting a 422 Unprocessable Entity response that means `@goal.save` isn't working - likely because of a validation requirement on your Goal model? Print `@goal.errors` in your console before you save it if you want to see exactly why.